# How to get and display locations/addresses on user text input

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms, geolocation, geocoding

I am building a small Xamarin forms application that requires me to display addresses based on user input without showing maps to users. i am using Geolocator Plugin to get positions and addresses.

I want users to be able to get addresses(not coordinates) when they enter text into an entry and then filter addresses to the user so the user can select a particular addresses from the results.

Answer (score 1):

this process is called reverse geocoding - turning a latitude and longitude into a physical address or point-of-interest - and it handled by the Essentials [Geocoding plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)

```
var placemarks = await Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(lat, lon);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I am using CrossGeolocator.GetAddressForPosition(position) and it works well. However, I am looking to get addresses based on users input. Is there a way or plugin to do that ?

Comment: What kind of data is the user inputting?

Comment: String data such as an address and I want all addresses that match the user input to be returned

Comment: That is still not very clear.  If the user enters "100 Main St" what exactly would you want to display as a result?

Comment: When the user enters the above value. I want to return all addresses that contains or begins with the above input. Something like what Google places API do

Comment: Then why not use the Google Places API?

Comment: I was hoping to get some other library so I don't need to consume the API from scratch. But I'm left with no choice than to use Google Place API. Thanks